# Is it possible to center a div with an unspecified width that contains two floating div also with unspecified widths

Tags: centering, floating

I am trying to get two elements to sit side by side inside a div or other element, so both two elements are always centered in the page.

Here's the catch... I cannot use any fixed widths, it is dynamically generated by javascript. It would seem that from reading other posts that this is not possible without fixed widths, but I wanted to see if any one had any other ideas to achieve the same result.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="centerdiv">
        <div class = float1></div>
        <div class = float2></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {text-align: center; width: 100%;}
.centerdiv {margin: 0 auto;width: 100%}
div.float1 {float:left; display:inline;}
div.float2 {float:left; display:inline;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follwing code to center the div side by side.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {text-align: center; width: 100%;}
    .centerdiv {margin: 0 auto;width: 100%;margin-left:40%;}

    .float1{border:1px solid black;width:10%;float:left;}
    </style>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="centerdiv">
        <div class = float1>Hello</div>
        <div class = float1>Hai</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!!!!!!

Comment: Floats overlap on the right third of the window with this, but an interesting approach.